# JavaScript - Show numbers with decimals

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

I'm trying to show numbers in labels. If the number > 1000 the format should look like
**1.000** or **1,000**

I tried with toFixed but it is not the solution, also toPrecision but it gave me a number like 1,2e+

I tried with
**number/1000**
but when the number ends up with a 0, it disappears from the result, so how can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped up the following function. It will add a comma after 3 digits. Works on whole numbers.

```
function formatNumber(num)
{
    var formattedNumber = "";
    var numString = num.toString();
    var numCount = 0;

    for (var index = numString.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        if (numCount % 3 == 0 
               && numString[index] != '-'
               && formattedNumber)
        {
            formattedNumber = ',' + formattedNumber;
        }

        formattedNumber = numString[index] + formattedNumber;

        numCount++;
    } 

    return formattedNumber;
}
```

Comment: thanks, works perfect, except for the z.toString(); z doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own function. Something like this:

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

**EDIT:** Found the original code